# Meaning of lyrics from "505" by Arctic Monkeys

Tags: lyrics, meaning, indie

These lyrics are from the song "505" by Arctic Monkeys:

> 'Not shy of a spark,
>   A knife twists at the thought that I should fall short of the mark,
>   Frightened by the bite though its no harsher than the bark,
>   Middle of adventure, such a perfect place to start'

I've been wondering a lot about the meaning of these lyrics --Alex Turner is known for his profound lyrics.

Answer (score 5):

**A knife twists at the thought that I should fall short of the mark,**

*It’s much simpler than this. The idea of not measuring up to her desires causes him pain, which is commonly referred to a feeling of twisting the knife.*

**Frightened by the bite though its no harsher than the bark,**

*Following from the previous line, he is admitting that he knows what he has to do but he cant’t because he loves her hence going back. Alex is admitting to being stuck between a rock and a hard place*

**Middle of adventure, such a perfect place to start'**

*Here he’s trying to convince her to resume the relationship and also being aware that it will all end up in pain and suffering.*

source: https://genius.com/1511938